# Constructores anidados hasta 4to nivel de herencia, y objetos en los parámetros, no me esta funcionando la ultima herencia

Tags: c#

```
public Humano(string nom, ERaza raz)
{
   this.nombre = nom;
   this.raza = raz;
}


public Persona(string nombre,string ape, ERaza raza,sbyte ed):base(nombre,raza)
{
    base.nombre = nombre;
    base.raza = raza;
    this.apellido = ape;
    this.edad = ed;
}


public Alumno(Persona p,short leg, EnivelDeEstudio niv):base(p.nombre,p.apellido,p.raza,p.edad)
{
    this.legajo = leg;
    this.nivel = niv;
}


public AlumnoEgresado(Alumno a,float prome, short promo):base(a.)
{
    this.promedio = prome;
    this.promocion = promo;
}
```

Comment: Debes incluir el error; mira que Alumno su constructor tiene 3 parámetros y en AlumnoAgregado estas pasando solo uno (eso ademas que tiene un punto **:base(a.)**..

Answer (score 0):

los parametros de base del ultimo constructor no estan completos

```
   public Humano(string nom, ERaza raz)
{
   this.nombre = nom;
   this.raza = raz;
}


public Persona(string nombre,string ape, ERaza raza,sbyte ed):base(nombre,raza)
{
    base.nombre = nombre;
    base.raza = raza;
    this.apellido = ape;
    this.edad = ed;
}


public Alumno(Persona p,short leg, EnivelDeEstudio niv):base(p.nombre,p.apellido,p.raza,p.edad)
{
    this.legajo = leg;
    this.nivel = niv;
}


public AlumnoEgresado(Alumno a,float prome, short promo):base(a.legajo,a.nivel,a.nombre,a.apellido,a.raza,a.edad)
{
    this.promedio = prome;
    this.promocion = promo;
}
```

Comment: Cuando completo el ultimo base como vos, me dice que el constructor de la clase alumno, no recibe 6 argumentos.